# Jquery-validator input file not being validated

Tags: jquery, file, jquery-validate

Can anyone tell me why isn't the rules entry working?
I'm trying to validate the input file. It should be required. 
Adding a class="required" works fine, but adding the required rule, apparently not...

**EDIT:**

The documentation (in the accept option) isn't of much help since it tests with a text input and not a file input.

There is also a good [example](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/errorcontainer-demo.html) but the validation is inline and i'd like to see how to make the rules work instead..
You can find a jsFiddle of this same code in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/snQTn/).

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    byRules: "required"
                }
            })
        });

    </script>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" action="" >
        Required by rules: <input id="byRules" type="file"><br/>
        Required by class: <input id="byClass" type="file" class="required"><br/>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**ANSWER:**

Got it! The thing is, with files, the id is not the "id" attribute, but the "name" attribute!
So, adding **name="byRules"** in the first input makes the validation work.

Phew! :)

Comment: Have you included the validate plugin _before_ this script?

Comment: can you provide sample on jsfiddle or so? Like this it looks OK

Comment: Yes, thanks! It's in here: http://jsfiddle.net/snQTn/
Oh, and yes, i've added everything before :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it! The thing is, with files, the id is not the "id" attribute, but the "name" attribute! So, adding `name="byRules"` in the first input makes the validation work.

Phew! :)